# What are the north side and south side magnetic metals called?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, terminology, metals

What are the two metals that cause the repel force of a north side magnet, and the attract force force of a south side magnet?

Answer (score 1):

A magnet is created by aligning the magnetic fields of very small atomic level domains throughout the material. We know this because a sufficiently powerful external magnetic field can realign or even reverse the field of a magnet. You don’t need to have two different metals to create a magnet.